# using HDR maps in LWJGL 3

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently using LWJGL 3 and building a simple skybox. I want the skybox to take in a HDR file, an equirectangular map. I can get a skybox running with a PNG with PNGDecoder but unsure how it would work with an HDR file. From what I understand, STB (as it is in c++) allows for the HDR file to be uploaded in the program, and LWJGL 3 has STB support.

How would I go about making a loadTexture function that supports STB and an HDR file?

EDIT: I'm going to post my progress to so anyone can see what I've been working on.

1. My loader class holds all my loadTexture methods and I'm using an int method that stores the texture ID, currently the method looks like this:

   ```
   public int loadCubeMap(String textureFile) throws IOException {

    int texID = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    ByteBuffer imageBuffer;
    IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    ByteBuffer image;

    imageBuffer = IOUtil.ioResourceToByteBuffer(textureFile, 8 * 1024);

    if (!stbi_info_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp))
        throw new IOException("Failed to read image information: " + stbi_failure_reason());

    image = stbi_load_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp, 3);

    if (image == null)
        throw new IOException("Failed to load image: " + stbi_failure_reason());
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, w.get(0), h.get(0), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    stbi_image_free(image);

    return texID; }
   ```

Which I got from this demo lwjgl3-demos [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/textures/EnvironmentDemo.java) with an example of an environment map using an HDR texture and using the STBImage java bindings. The method also uses a class in my utils package called IOUtil, which is from the example and works in the sample. (I also tried the HDR file from the learnOpengl tutorials which works fine with the example, but not with my own code);

I have a skybox shader and a skybox renderer which all seem to work well. The skybox renderer is written as below:

public class SkyboxRenderer {

```
private static final float SIZE = 500f;

private static final float[] VERTICES = {        
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,

     SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,

    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE,  SIZE,
    -SIZE,  SIZE, -SIZE,

    -SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE, -SIZE,
    -SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE,
     SIZE, -SIZE,  SIZE
};

private RawModel cube;
private int skyboxTexture;
private SkyboxShader shader;

public SkyboxRenderer(Loader loader, Matrix4f projectionMatrix) throws IOException {
    cube = loader.loadToVAO(VERTICES, 3);
    skyboxTexture = loader.loadCubeMap("res/newport_loft.hdr");
    shader = new SkyboxShader();
    shader.start();
    shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    shader.connectTextureUnits();
    shader.stop();
    }

public void render(Camera camera) {
    shader.start();
    shader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(cube.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, skyboxTexture);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, cube.getVertexCount());
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    shader.stop();
    }
}
```

I am using a vertex and fragment shader which came from learnOpengl's PBR tutorial.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core 

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec3 WorldPos;

uniform mat4 projection; 
uniform mat4 view;

void main() {
    WorldPos = aPos;  
    gl_Position =  projection * view * vec4(WorldPos, 1.0); }
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 WorldPos;

uniform sampler2D equirectangularMap;

const vec2 invAtan = vec2(0.1591, 0.3183);
vec2 SampleSphericalMap(vec3 v)
{
    vec2 uv = vec2(atan(v.z, v.x), asin(v.y));
    uv *= invAtan;
    uv += 0.5;
    return uv;
}

void main()
{       
    vec2 uv = SampleSphericalMap(normalize(WorldPos));
    vec3 color = texture(equirectangularMap, uv).rgb;

    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

The shader code works as well as it does, from the help of Thinmatrix's tutorials.

public class SkyboxShader extends ShaderProgram{

```
private static final String VERTEX_FILE = "src/skybox/cubemap.vs";
private static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = "src/skybox/cubemap.fs";

private int location_projectionMatrix;
private int location_viewMatrix;

private int location_equirectangularMap;

public SkyboxShader() {
    super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
}

public void loadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f matrix){
    super.loadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, matrix);
}

public void loadViewMatrix(Camera camera){
    Matrix4f matrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
    super.loadMatrix(location_viewMatrix, matrix);
}

@Override
protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
    location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projection");
    location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("view");
    location_equirectangularMap = super.getUniformLocation("equirectangularMap");
}

@Override
protected void bindAttributes() {
    super.bindAttribute(0, "aPos");
}

public void connectTextureUnits() {
    super.loadInt(location_equirectangularMap, 0);
} }
```

I initialize the loadCubeMap function in the skybox renderer along with the file name, then initialize the skybox renderer in the master renderer class.

By the time I run it, I get no errors about the HDR texture and the loader, so I assume its accepting it. Most of it works.

[image: here]

I get a box and a texture, but the texture is binding to the wrong texture. Its binding the albedo ground texture that I use in my terrain, which I suppose is the default condition when things are not binding correctly, just guessing.

Edit: I just realized that the HDR map is used for a sphere, and I'm rendering a cube. (lol)

So there, I can't seem to figure out the problem. I will give it another whirl and see what I can improve on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

So I've tried reworking it. The image variable was changed to a Float Buffer and now accepts image with stbi_loadf_from_memory. Still a but confused, didn't think HDR maps would be this confusing.

```
public int loadCubeMap(String textureFile) throws IOException {

         int texID = glGenTextures();
         //glActiveTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
         glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

         ByteBuffer imageBuffer;
         IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
         IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
         IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
         FloatBuffer image;

         imageBuffer = IOUtil.ioResourceToByteBuffer(textureFile, 8 * 1024);

         if (!stbi_info_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp))
             throw new IOException("Failed to read image information: " + stbi_failure_reason());

         image = stbi_loadf_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp, 3);



         if (image == null)
             throw new IOException("Failed to load image: " + stbi_failure_reason());
         glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16, w.get(0), h.get(0), 0, GL_RGB16, GL_FLOAT, image);

         stbi_image_free(image);

         return texID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`stbi_load_from_memory()`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage.html#stbi_load_from_memory-java.nio.ByteBuffer-java.nio.IntBuffer-java.nio.IntBuffer-java.nio.IntBuffer-int-) You should use [`stbi_loadf_from_memory()`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage.html#stbi_loadf_from_memory-java.nio.ByteBuffer-int:A-int:A-int:A-int-), which is the function that reads HDR files. STB also contains functions such as [`stbi_is_hdr_from_memory()`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage.html#stbi_is_hdr_from_memory-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) that allows you to ensure that the buffer contains an HDR image.

Note that `stbi_load_from_memory()` returns a `FloatBuffer` containing the texture.

In addition, you should modify the call to `glTexImage2D()`:

- replace `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` with `GL_FLOAT`, as the buffer now contains a `float` for each component, and
- pick an appropriate floating point internal format, such as `GL_RGB16F` to replace `GL_RGB8`.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So far I change the Bytebuffer image into a FloatBuffer. And changed the image = stbi_load_from_memory to stbi_loadf_from_memory. The error check that I have still remains the same, and IntBuffers for the w, h and comp variables are the same. The GL_RGB16F cannot be found, and Im sure I have current versions of the libraries.

Comment: Also, I have an example that seems to load the HDR image fine, yet doesnt need the stbi_loadf or the appropriate floating point to work. I'm assuming its because you only need it if you want to use the HDR image to the fullest extent.

Comment: (1) GL_RGB16F should be available, see http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL30.html#GL_RGB16F , (2) HDR, as in High Dynamic Range, usually requires floating point values to store a much larger range of values.